# How TO - Include HTML

Tags: javascript, html

i want to include HTML Nav Bar, in Index HTML File.
(I prefer to follow suit) I do not know what wrong I did, but it does not show me the Nav bar..

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Home Page</title>
        <script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div w3-include-html="navbar.html"></div>

        <script>
            w3.includeHTML();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can OR solve this with PHP, as @floreich mentioned, otherwise I see your code is correct but perhaps your path to the file is not correct.

I mean this line of code: `<div w3-include-html="navbar.html"></div>`.

Try to navigate to the correct path of your file called 'navbar.html', and it should work. Let me know! :)

This might help:

```
<div w3-include-html="dir/navbar.html"></div>
```

As you can see 'dir/' is added before 'navbar.html', which is a directory where 'navbar.html' is located.

Perhaps this explanation might help to understand above: https://www.w3schools.com/hTml/html_filepaths.asp

**EDIT:**

'dir/' is just a name, so change it to YOUR directory name.

Comment: The Problem was the Web Server, (the code does not work in the google Chrome and Internet Explore). The Code work in the Firefox. Thank you very much :)

Comment: If you wish to have it working in chrome and IE, perhaps you might want to use include php instead of html tags (which not works except firefox). Include through php will work in any browser